# How can i modify the title in a CGridView column?

Tags: gridview, yii

I have table **News** with a **category** field where I store the id of the category and a related table **NewsCategories** which has the fields **id** and **category_name**.

What do I have to modify to show **category_name** instead of **id**?

Here is my News.php model

```
class News extends CActiveRecord
{   


public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'news';
}


public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('title, date, description, content, category', 'required'),
        array('category', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('title, image', 'length', 'max'=>256),
        array('image','file','types'=>'jpg,jpeg,gif,png','allowEmpty'=>true),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, title, date, image, description, content, category', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}


public function relations()
{

    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    'category'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'NewsCategories', 'category'),
    );
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => '#',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'date' => 'Date',
        'image' => 'Image',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'content' => 'Content',
        'category' => 'Category',
    );
}


public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
    $criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);
    $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
    $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);
    $criteria->compare('content',$this->content,true);
    $criteria->compare('category',$this->category);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
 }
```

And my NewsCategories.php model

```
class NewsCategories extends CActiveRecord
{

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}


public function tableName()
{
    return 'news_categories';
}


public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('category_name', 'required'),
        array('category_name', 'length', 'max'=>64),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, category_name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    'news'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'News', 'category'),
    );
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'category_name' => 'Название рубрики',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('category_name',$this->category_name,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
}
```

Here peace of admin.php wich control panel:

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'news-categories-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
   //   'id',
       'title',
    'date',
    //'image',
    'description',
    'content',
    'category',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',

         ),
    ),
 ));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'tasks',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filter'=>$task,
    'ajaxUrl'=>bu('office/view/officeId/'.$officeId),
    'columns'=>array(
        'summary',
        'due',
        array(
            'header'=>'Assigned to'
            'value'=> '$data->ownerUserName',
            'name'=> 'ownerUserName',
            'sortable'=>true,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model you are having the relation name same as one of the attribute name that is "category" don't give relation name same as attribute name

change the relation name to anything other than category

e.g newsCategory

then in relation

```
'newsCategory'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'NewsCategories', 'category'),
```

Try this

```
'columns'=>array(
  'id',
  'title',
  array(
    'name' => 'category',
    'value' => '$data->newsCategory->category_name'
  ),
  .......


)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have relation defined in News model so that it would not conflict with attribute name `category`:

```
'newsCategory'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'NewsCategories', 'category'),
```

and then

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
        'newsCategory.category_name',  // display the 'category_name' attribute of the 'category' relation
    ),
));
```

Comment: It only changing name of column but not content

Comment: Please edit you original question and add your News and NewsCategories models and view file code because it is hard to grasp what is the exact problem.

Comment: Thank you. Your relation name is conflicting with attribute "category". See @Neophile answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is what do in case I need to display something from related models or different from model attributes in grid (Assuming that you have defined `News` propery called `categoryModel` which is instance of reated model `NewsCategories`)

Part of `CGridView` definition:

```
.......
'columns'=>array(
    'title',  // standard attribute
    array( // specific data
        'name'=>'Post Category', // col title
        'value'=>function (News $model){ //dataprovider must return instance of News class
            if(!$model->category)
                return "No category";

            return $model->categoryModel->category_name;
        }
    ),
)
......
```

It requires php version>=5.3. 
But it can be rewriten for older versions easy.

Comment: Also one good thing to do is to modify your Model's search method to join the referenced table, so you don't need to lazy load each referenced model separately.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add the attribute `categoryName`, and function `afterFind()`:

```
class News extends CActiveRecord {

    public $categoryName = "";

    protected function afterFind() {
        $cat = NewsCategories::model()->findByPk($this->category);
        if(isset($cat)) $this->categoryName = $cat->category_name;

        return parent::afterFind();
    }
```

In your CGridView, use `categoryName`:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'title',
    'date',
    array(
        'label'=>$model->getAttributeLabel('image'),
        'type'=>'image',
        'value'=>($model->image== '') ? '' : $baseUrl.'/'.$model->image,
    ),
    'description',
    'content',
    'categoryName',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```